# Javascript - alerting content on click of dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript

I have a code where 3 button elements are created dynamically, and when they are created I would like to alert each buttons `textContent`, but when I do so, only the last element is alerted, others are not. Why is that?

```
var list = new Array("en", "to", "tre");

for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = list[i]; 
    document.body.appendChild(button)
}

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert(this.textContent);
});
```

Comment: You're only calling `addEventListener` on the last button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each value of `i`, `button` is different. At the end of the loop, `button` is still only the last element. You should put the event listener inside the loop like so:

```
var list = new Array("en", "to", "tre");

for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = list[i]; 
    document.body.appendChild(button);

    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert(this.textContent);
    });

}
```

Also, using `new Array( a, b, c )` is highly discouraged, consider switching to `[ a, b, c ]`. It doesn't break your code, but is definitely worth noting

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the event listener to the last button only.

Move it inside the loop, like this:

```js
var list = new Array("en", "to", "tre");

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  button = document.createElement("button");
  button.textContent = list[i];
  document.body.appendChild(button)
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(this.textContent);
  });
}
```